# Serialzing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Rule object

Tags: c#, serialization, com, office-interop, outlook-addin

So I'm looking for a way to serialize the outlook rules from within an Outlook-Addin.

Getting the rules is quite simple

```
var rules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules();
foreach (Outlook.Rule rule in rules)
{
    //Serialize the rule
}
```

but so far I haven't found any `OK` way to serialize the `Rule` object so that it can either be stored in a file or sent over the wire.

The only way I can think of is to implement all the classes used within `Rule` and then copying elements to them one-by-one and then serialize those classes using either XML/JSON serializer. But the problem with this approach is that the number of nested classes is significantly high.
Is there any simpler way to serilze the `Rule` COM object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Outlook rules are not serializable using the Outlook Object Model. Also keep in mind that rules can contain local data (such as folder entry ids) - such a data will not work if a rule is restored in a different store.

Comment: any recommendation or advice to go about it?